# How to receive APNS for some actions and for some not

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In some apps like QuizUp, there is a section in Settings (in the app), Push Notifications and the user can tell if he wants to receive APNS for, lets say new friend request, but to turn off for new challenge. How can I achieve that within the app?

Comment: I can agree with that. Thank you. If you want you can post it as a answer because it clarifies my guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can achieved with your back end team. You need to call a web services for stop notification for the particular activity.

You can arrange its screen like setting as you mention and based on your each activity functionality you can stop and active Notification for user.

I don't think that you can be handle from Application side. As par my thinking you just need to call web-services.